# Style tables in mobile so they go full width and scroll if content is longer

Tags: html, css, html-table, scroll, overflow

I'm searching for a pure-CSS solution to make tables behave in the following way:

- if the content

  - the table should always fill the width of its container, with cells distributing horizontally
  - the table should scroll horizontally if its content is wider than the width of the container

If I use

```css
table {
  width: 100%
}
```

it will work fine for tables whose content is shorter than the width of the content, whether if I use

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

will work fine with tables whose content is larger than the width of the content. Is there a way to make the table behave in both ways?

I hope it's easier to understand with an example:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

p {
  font-style: italic;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

div#container {
  width: 600px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

thead {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
}

table.fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
}

table.displayblock {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}

table::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

table::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
  height: 11px;
}

table::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">

    <table class="fullwidth">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>col1</td>
          <td>col2</td>
          <td>col3</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>short</td>
          <td>table</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>Tables with short contents shoould behave like this.</p>

    <table class="displayblock">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>col1</td>
          <td>col2</td>
          <td>col3</td>
          <td>col4</td>
          <td>col5</td>
          <td>col6</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td>someverywidetable</td>
        <td>someverywidetable</td>
        <td>someverywidetable</td>
        <td>someverywidetable</td>
        <td>someverywidetable</td>
        <td>someverywidetable</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>Tables with long contents should behave like this.</p>
    

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

In the example I used two different styles. Is it possibile to obtain the same effect with just one style?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i fixed your html as your are using individual tables for each row instead of using the standard. **TR** which stands for **Table Row**

Then i used flex box to position and align items inside the box.

if you want to predefine for mobile you have to use *media queries*

> https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

```css
h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 90vw;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;

  /*position container in the middle of page*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table {
  /*position center*/
  margin: 0 auto;

  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 2.5vh 3vw;
  width: 84vw; /*container width - padding*/
}

tr {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  border: 2.5px solid black;
}

td {
  /*width 33% of parent*/
  width: 100%;

  /*center text in box*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  /*fit inside box*/
  word-break: break-all;

  /*see table cells*/
  background: #fff333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=2.0,user-scalable=1">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>short</td>
          <td>table</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>someverywidetable</td>
          <td>someverywidetable</td>
          <td>someverywidetable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>short</td>
          <td>table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>someverywidetable</td>
          <td>someverywidetable</td>
          <td>someverywidetable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>short</td>
          <td>table</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>someverywidetable</td>
          <td>someverywidetable</td>
          <td>someverywidetable</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Stanley for your answer. I'm afraid I did not explain well my problem. The tables in the example have just one row but each one represent a different table. Also, my problem is not necessarily with mobile layout, but can be also related to desktop. I will try to edit my post to make it more clear.

Comment: @jacopo i still dont understand. can you draw a mockup?

Comment: I simplified more my example! I think its very clear now!

Comment: @jacopo ahh okay, you want the snippet to work on both types of tables like an if statement?

Comment: Exactly! I was wandering if there is some kind of CSS trick to get this behavior.

Comment: I couldnt figure it out unfortunately. Only with js